# Xamarin Android Rendering Issues

Tags: android, macos, xamarin

I have an issue with Xamarin , when one day your Xamarin Android app works perfectly, then precisely this happens:

1. You send it to the store. And add keys: `<uses-sdk target=27 min=23>`
2. App gets released in the store, but now it has peculiar UI issues

All things that have had rounded corners or were circles, thank's to OutlineProvider, became rectangular.

If you try and run your app in Genymotion emulator, app has about 10 fps, and the log constantly tells you that you are doing too much work in the wrong place.
Yes , and preceding all these events was an update of macOS to Mojave.
I'm really wondering if anyone has come over this situation with Xamarin Android, when one day your app is all right, and the next, it is all screwed up, without any observable reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I have placed my `<uses-sdk>` tag in the manifest under the `<application></application>` tag.